# How to parse data from a mysql tracking db?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a working event tracker that writes every event in a mysql table.

Table

```
id      date                userid      event
5100    2014-03-25 14:18:55 user333     AI  
5101    2014-03-25 14:19:02 user333     Click
5102    2014-03-25 14:19:02 user333     Click
...
```

Thats works so far very good. But now, I want to write a little report tool in node.js

I try to get the values with this SQL Query:

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,"%Y%m%d") AS date, event, count(*) AS count FROM databasetest WHERE date>="'+ daystartdate +'" AND date<="'+ dayenddate +'" GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date), event

Giving me this:

```
+----------+----------+-------+
| date     | event    | count |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 20140320 | AI       |     6 |
| 20140320 | Click    |     2 |
| 20140320 | swipe    |     2 |
| 20140321 | Click    |     6 |
| 20140321 | error    |     5 |
| 20140321 | swipe    |     2 |
| 20140321 | touch    |     3 |
| 20140322 | AI       |     3 |
| 20140322 | Click    |     3 |
| 20140322 | error    |     1 |
| 20140322 | mapsload |     3 |
| 20140322 | touch    |     1 |
| 20140323 | AI       |     2 |
| 20140323 | Click    |     2 |
| 20140323 | touch    |     5 |
| 20140324 | AI       |     3 |
| 20140324 | Click    |     1 |
| 20140325 | AI       |    25 |
| 20140325 | Click    |    48 |
| 20140325 | error    |    16 |
| 20140325 | mapsload |     7 |
| 20140325 | swipe    |    15 |
| 20140325 | touch    |    32 |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

But I need the data in this form:

```
+----------+----------+-------+-----
| date     | Click    | AI    | ....
+----------+----------+-------+-----
| 20140320 | 0        |     6 |
| 20140321 | 2        |     2 |
| 20140321 | 2        |     5 |
```

Is this possible with a SQL query or do I need to loop through the results in my javascript code. I tried many possible solution but didnt get it to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common question, keywords to search are "transpose" and "pivot". To save you the trouble, this is something that MySQL is not able to do. SQL Server (a MS product) can do this, though.

You will need to loop through the output and build the result set yourself.

```
var results = []
data.forEach(function(row, rowidx) {
  results[row.date] = results[row.date] || {};
  results[row.date][row.event] = results[row.date][row.event] || 0;
  results[row.date][row.event] += row.count;
});
```